# Repeat Single based on onSuccess() value

Tags: rx-java2

I want to repeat a `Single` based on the single value emitted in `onSuccess()`. Here is a working example

```
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.functions.Function;

public class Temp {

    void main() {
        Job job = new Job();

        Single.just(job)
                .map(this::processJob)
                .repeatWhen(new Function<Flowable<Object>, Publisher<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<?> apply(Flowable<Object> objectFlowable) throws Exception {
                        // TODO repeat when Single emits false
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
    }

    /**
     * returns true if process succeeded, false if failed
     */
    boolean processJob(Job job) {
        return true;
    }

    class Job {
    }
}
```

I understand how `repeatWhen` works for Observables by relying on the "complete" notification. However since Single doesn't receive that notification I'm not sure what the `Flowable<Object>` is really giving me. Also why do I need to return a `Publisher` from this function?

Comment: Single does not have `onNext` method, it has `onSuccess` instead.

Comment: @Benjamin brain fart; updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on a boolean value, you could make your job throw an exception when it fails:

```
class Job {
    var isSuccess: Boolean = false
}

fun processJob(job: Job): String {
    if (job.isSuccess) {
        return "job succeeds"
    } else {
        throw Exception("job failed")
    }
}

val job = Job()
Single.just(job)
        .map { processJob(it) }
        .retry() // will resubscribe until your job succeeds
        .subscribe(
                { value -> print(value) },
                { error -> print(error) }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this was my "stopgap" solution until I heard back on this question. Now it's my "final" solution.

Comment: @tir38 See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i saw a small discrepancy in the latest [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#retryWhen-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) and your code, so i did a little digging...

(side note - i think the semantics of `retryWhen` seem like the more appropriate operator for your case, so i've substituted it in for your usage of `repeatWhen`. but i think the root of your problem remains the same in either case).

the signature for `retryWhen` is:

```
retryWhen(Function<? super Flowable<Throwable>,? extends Publisher<?>> handler)
```

that parameter is a factory function whose input is a source that emits anytime `onError` is called upstream, giving you the ability to insert custom retry logic that may be influenced through interrogation of the underlying `Throwable`. this begins to answer your first question of "I'm not sure what the `Flowable<Object>` is really giving me" - it shouldn't be `Flowable<Object>` to begin with, it should be `Flowable<Throwable>` (for the reason i just described).

so where did `Flowable<Object>` come from? i managed to reproduce IntelliJ's generation of this code through it's auto-complete feature using RxJava version `2.1.17`. upgrading to `2.2.0`, however, produces the correct result of `Flowable<Throwable>`. so, see if upgrading to the latest version generates the correct result for you as well.

as for your second question of "Also why do I need to return a `Publisher` from this function?" - this is used to determine if re-subscription should happen. if the factory function returns a `Publisher` that emits a terminal state (ie calls `onError()` or `onComplete()`) re-subscription will not happen. however, if `onNext()` is called, it will. (this also explains why the `Publisher` isn't typed - the type doesn't matter. the only thing that does matter is what kind of notification it publishes).

another way to rewrite this, incorporating the above, might be as follows:

```
// just some type to use as a signal to retry
private class SpecialException extends RuntimeException {}

// job processing results in a Completable that either completes or 
// doesn't (by way of an exception)
private Completable rxProcessJob(Job job) {
    return Completable.complete();
    // return Completable.error(new SpecialException());
}

...

rxProcessJob(new Job())
        .retryWhen(errors -> {
            return errors.flatMap(throwable -> {
                if(throwable instanceof SpecialException) {
                    return PublishProcessor.just(1);
                }

                return PublishProcessor.error(throwable);
            });
        })
        .subscribe(
                () -> {
                    System.out.println("## onComplete()");
                },
                error -> {
                    System.out.println("## onError(" + error.getMessage() + ")");
                }
        );
```

i hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer would work, but is hackish. You don't need to throw an error; simply filter the output of `processJob` which converts the `Single` to a `Maybe`, and then use the `repeatWhen` handler to decide how many times, or with what delay, you may want to resubscribe. See Kotlin code below from a working example, you should be able to easily translate this to Java.

```
filter { it }
.repeatWhen { handler ->
    handler.zipWith(1..3) { _, i -> i }
        .flatMap { retryCount -> Flowable.timer(retryDelay.toDouble().pow(retryCount).toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
        .doOnNext { log.warn("Retrying...") }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear how this answers the question. There was no mention of retry count, etc. The question was, how can you repeat the request _based on the received `Single` value_.